# Silverlight causing Software Center to crash

Tags: software-center, google-chrome

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit system. I installed `silverlight` plugin to view netflix on Chrome browser. When I tried to load **Software Center**, it crashed on startup. I tried again through terminal(with root permission) and found the program was accessing silverlight for some reason and then crashed.

I disabled silverlight and tried again to see that software center loads without any hitches!

What does software center have to do with silverlight? Can I make it work with silverlight enabled?

Comment: You don't need silverlight with Google Chrome to begin with. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/psa-netflix-ubuntu-now-working-box

Comment: Yeah I realised that when I tried to play netflix on chrome. I thought I needed it because I saw it on `webupd8.org`. I just uninstalled pipelight.

Comment: However I still dont understand why silverlight interferes with **Software Center**